# OCR algorithm- distinguish between textual image and object image

Tags: ocr

Am writing a program that extracts the contents from the logo of different websites.. i am using OCR to extract the text from the logo but i want to optimize the program and want to apply OCR only on those logos which have text but i dont know how to determine if a logo contains text or not??? any method??

Comment: maybe you can try machine learning. reduce the image to 20-by-20 train a classifier with labeled data. image has letters 1, or -1. and see how well the in-sample-errors and out-of-sample-errors are. if the accuracy can hit like 90 something percent, it would be worth to use. since predicting will be very easy, you only need sometime to train and see the result. (libsvm is what you are going to start with)

Comment: Hi Fivesheep, thanks for your response but are you talking about the training images that stores the text images?? simple OCR algo already uses this.. but if i input a complicated image like logo of paypal or ebay , it outputs random value , infact for non text based  image also it gives a random output which i dont want but to skip the image.. i took the simple OCR code from  http://code.google.com/p/opencms-backoffice/source/browse/?r=125#svn%2Fbranches%2Ftest-ocr%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Froncemer%2Focr%2Fmain

Answer (score 3):

this is a case where we need to know if an image has text in it. It is different from OCR.

The algorithm which is considered to be best to date is Stroke Width Transform. It was designed by Ephstein under Microsoft in 2010. It doesn't use any machine learning purposes.

You can get more details from this paper : [Detecting Text in Natural Scenes with Stroke Width Transform](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf)

[Or watch a video about this.](http://videolectures.net/cvpr2010_epshtein_dtns/)

There is an implementation of this algorithm [here](https://sites.google.com/site/roboticssaurav/strokewidthnokia).

Comment: thanks Abid Rahman K.. working on it.. the code is in C++ but am working in java.. will there be java code availabe for it?

Comment: sorry i cant upvote your answer bcoz of my reputation in SOF.

Comment: Regarding the java code, i don't know if any. Actually it is under microsoft, and as you can see in the video, if you need real code, you need to be in Microsoft. And it is difficult to find enough details about SWT except the very few papers.